# join in sql query gives column ambigios error

Tags: mysql

**table name** - city

**columns** -city_id,city_name

**table** - state

**column**  -state_id,state_name

**table name** - category

column name - category_id,category_name

**table name** -  news

**column name** -  cat_id,state_id,city_id,headline,story ,author etc..

**I nedd to select all column from city,state,and category table for inserting id in news table....**

**for that I create sql query and join all above three table but this shows error ..plz help me...**

**Column 'state_id' in field list is ambiguous**

**Column 'city_id' in field list is ambiguous**

**Column 'category_id' in field list is ambiguous**

**I need to return all columns from city,state and category table**

```
SELECT city_name,city_id,state_id,category_id,state_name,category_name,headline,author,story,source,photo,date from news left join
 city on news.city_id=city.city_id left join state on news.state_id=state.state_id left join category on news.cat_id=category.category_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the tables where the columns come from.  `city_id` is ambiguous in the `select` list.  I think this is the right aliases:

```
SELECT c.city_name, c.city_id, s.state_id, ca.category_id, s.state_name, ca.category_name,
       n.headline, n.author, n.story, n.source, n.photo, n.date
from news n left join
     city c
     on n.city_id= c.city_id left join
     state s
     on n.state_id = s.state_id left join
     category ca
     on n.cat_id = ca.category_id;
```

Note that I introduced table aliases.  These help make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Unknown column 'c.city_name' in 'field list' then also for  Unknown column 'c.city_id' in 'on clause' same for category and state and all

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the same is, you have state_id both in state and news table (same for city_id which is in City as well as news table) to name few and SQL engine is confused which one to use. Hence i would advice you to use table alias or table name as prefix in the select fields.